# Where can I find the page breaks option?

Tags: cognito-forms

I watched the video about how to create new pages. The page break option does not exist under "Layout".

Comment: I'm a developer with Cognito Forms. You might be trying to add a page break to a section or a repeating section. In order for us to better understand the issue your having can you submit a support request (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/)?